# BeautifulSoup, get_text(), splitlines(), how to remove empty lines in pythonic one liner?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there a one liner where I can get the text from the soup object, then use splitlines to get a list of each line in the html. Then remove all the excess empty lines in the list that just have newline in it.

I don't want to write another for loop to pass thru twice and clean up the new lines. Also, any other pythonic way to do this is appreciated.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('myhtml.html', 'html.parser')
sections = soup.findAll(div, class_='section')
lines = []
for section in sections:
    lines = lines + section.get_text().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
lines = lines + [l for l in sections.get_text().splitlines() if l]
```

Alternatively, a `filter`:

```
lines = lines + list(filter(None, sections.get_text().splitlines()))
```

Furthermore, you may shorten this to

```
lines += ...
```

---

If you want to get rid of the loop even, here's what you do:

```
lines = [l for section in soup.findAll(div, class_='section')\
              for l in section.get_text().splitlines() if l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *real* one-liner :)

```
from itertools import chain
lines = list(chain.from_iterable([l for l in section.get_text().splitlines() if l] 
                   for section in soup.findAll(div, class_='section')))
```

Comment: If you want to play dirty, how about `[l for section in sections for l in section.get_text().splitlines() if l]` :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Touche!

Comment: @DYZ FYI - When I click on the link in your profile/bio for the data science book I get directed a login page, can't see the book.